# iOS: If 'swipe to delete' is enabled should I still have an edit button?

Tags: ios, user-experience

Basically, as the title of the question says: I would like to know how important it is to have an edit button when all I want the user to be able to do to a cell is delete and 'swipe to delete' is enabled. Is it intuitive enough if the edit button is not there? Are iOS users all very familiar with 'swipe to delete'??

I would rather not have the edit button there if I'm able to delete by swiping, but how would a user know?

Comment: You will probably get a better response to this question on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not all users known the Swipe to delete.

Comment: you dont have to put edit button, as a user and as a developer I believe that most IOS users are familiar with `swipe to delete` even if there is no edit button in the `tableview` , examples:IOS built-in Notes App, Dropbox App etc...

Comment: A brand new iOS user wouldn't be familiar with it, and see the iOS built in Messages app, that provides both the edit button and swipe features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is personal preference.  I believe the swipe to delete is more of a super-user feature and people new to iOS may not find it, if you see the Apple Message app, both are supported, you can swipe to delete or press edit then delete.

However, see the Apple Notes app, and swipe to delete is the only way to delete a note without actually going in to it.

Analyse your target user base and make a decision, or try observing some people using the feature.  Is there a reason why you can't have an edit button?  Is something else in the nav bar?

As CodeBox says, this is more of a user-experience discussion than a right/wrong programming question.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/